# Audio Volume in Apple's speakHere example code

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, volume, speaker

I am trying to increase the volume of my Audio Output using the speakHere example from Apple. The volume is already set to max with :

// set the volume of the queue
    XThrowIfError (AudioQueueSetParameter(mQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, 1.0), "set queue volume");

However, the output is directed to the ear-piece speaker, which is not as loud as the bottom-left-speaker on the iPhone. An example of this can be seen nicely in the 'Voice Memos' that comes with the iPhone. They provide a 'Speaker-Button' that toggles between the two speakers. Does anybody have an idea how that is done? What do I need to output my Audio to the bottom speaker? 
Any tips, hints, answers will be much appreciated.
Thanks you in advance
Al

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set Player to Speaker Mode.

Add this code in AQPlayer.mm:

```
OSStatus error;
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker; 
error = AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof (audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);
if (error) printf("couldn't set audio speaker!");
```

Before this code:

```
XThrowIfError (AudioQueueSetParameter(mQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, 1.0), "set queue volume");
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at AudioSessionSetProperty, the kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker property in particular.

Answer (score 2):

look at the kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute property